# Proving struct field's lifetime outlives another lifetime

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm working on a lexer in Rust.

Desired API:

```
enum Token<'input> {
    Name(&'input str)
}

let mut lexicon = LexiconBuilder::<Token>::new()
    .token("[a-zA-Z]+", |s| Token::Name(s))
    // among others
    .build();

let mut lexer = Lexer::new(lexicon, "input");
```

The idea is the user can provide a regular expression, along with a closure that gets run when the regex matches the input text. However, I'm having trouble proving to the lifetime checker that the slice that gets passed into `token()`'s closure lives long enough. From my POV, it seems safe, as the tokens aren't returned until you provide a string.

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3812723db510671e16fdb1eb1b842abd)

I've spent quite awhile trying to thread input lifetime through all of the types, however I can't ever seem to prove that the lexicon's (ergo, the rule's handler) lifetime will match/dominate the input's.

Comment: This API seems implausible to me, because it is strange that a lexer should be parameterized by the type of token it outputs -- I feel that would logically be determined by the lexer itself. `lexicon()` in particular stands out because there's almost never any reason to have a function with an output lifetime but no input lifetimes. I imagine there is *some* reason why you're not just doing [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1dd8ecf8ea714e3fa5eeb6f71a413c3b), but I figured I'd just mention it anyway.

Comment: Good feedback. I ended up having the lexer's `next()` method return the rule ID, the current slice, and the position. The library is meant to be substrate for the user's lexer, hence being parameterized by the token type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type Handler<T> = fn(&str) -> T;
```

Is not a complete type. The `&str` needs to have a lifetime on it, but one is not specified. Lifetime elision means that this expands to

```
type Handler<T> = for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> T;
```

So `Handler`s don't know the lifetime of the `&str`s being given to them. For some `'input`, to construct a `Rule<Token<'input>>`, you need a `Handler<Token<'input>>`, but that means you need `for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> Token<'input>`, where the `Token` wants a `&'input str` but you only have a `&'a str`. You need to make `'input` a parameter of `Handler`, so it can restrict the arguments it will accept:

```
type Handler<'input, T> = fn(&'input str) -> T;
```

And this must propagate through all your other types. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=429ae7ca356c75f7482ecdbb2a3a2481).

The code in your question is incomplete, and the code in the playground doesn't match it. If you've already tried this, then you're going to have to tell us what went wrong more clearly.

Comment: tl;dr essentially the issue is that you haven't told rust what the lifetime of the `T` returned by `Handler` is. If you returned a reference from the handler, rust could assume `fn(&'input str) -> &'input T` but since `T` is a value type with an internal reference, rust won't automatically do `fn(&'input str) -> T<'input>`

Comment: I understand. I'd propagated the lifetime through the types previously, but I think I made a mistake and couldn't get it to work, hence the barebones playground link. Thank you and @PitaJ for how to get unstuck.